# Define variable before javascript load

Tags: javascript, variables, external, var

I noticed that you can't import a javascript file and define a variable in the same `<script>`.

This is my problem:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js.js">
var id = "587587";
</script>
```

Is there a way to load the javascript after the variable without using another `<script>` tag?

Comment: Why *not* simply use another script tag...?!

Comment: You could first define the variable and then do something like `document.write('<script src="js.js"><\/script>')` in the javascript. But then again, why not insert the script tag manually?

Comment: Because I'll be implementing it into a system where users will copy the code into their own websites, so it needs to be clean.

Comment: Writing a script tag programmatically is typically what most analytics scripts do. But some also use a second script tag. IMO it's not any worse, the user needs to copy and paste some meaningless blob anyway, he'll hardly care what exactly that blob contains.

Comment: @George - perhaps you could ask the (maybe a different) question in a way that illustrates the problem you're trying to solve instead of a work around for not being able to use the script tag like you want. You might get better answers.

Comment: you can put url params in the script src, or find the linking tag from the external script, and examine the textContent to find config, or eval() it to run code.

Answer (score 1):

If a `script` tag has a `src` attribute, anything between the script tags is ignored. The only way you could do something like this is by dynamically adding a new script tag with an ugly hack like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var id = "587587";
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"><\/script>');
</script>
```

Using another script tag before the one with the id would certainly be the preferable and shorter solution.

Answer (score 0):

> `src`
>
> This attribute specifies the URI of an external script; this can be
>   used as an alternative to embedding a script directly within a
>   document. script elements with an src attribute specified should not
>   have a script embedded within its tags.
>
> http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script.html

So, you either have an external script, or you have something inside the `<script>` tag. You *shouldn't* have both at once; I'm not sure whether this actually does anything or not.

Use a second script tag.

Comment: the contents of a .scr-having tag don't "do anything", but they are present in the dom by any other script.

Comment: @dandavis *"...whether having source code within the tags when you already have a `src` attribute does anything..."*

Answer (score 0):

A script element must either contain script code between the script start and end tags, or reference external script code via the src= attribute. It cannot do both. However, your external code can reference the details of your HTML via the DOM (Document Object Model). So you can treat any HTML element (e.g. a text input field) as a parameter to be passed to your external javascript, where it can be read by e.g. var param = document.getElementById('param').innerHTML;